# How do i check a type against its parent class?

Tags: generics, dart, generic-programming

Simple cases of, int being a number really.

Im creating a generic `class test<T>`

and i want to test T to see if its inherited from number (or num in the case of Dart).

Based on the Objects,    `Object > num > int` in the docs, so at first I was thinking that:  `T is num` would work if `T` is `int`.  Testing `int is num` shows false.  There must be another keyword i need to use instead of `is` to determine if it is a child of a particular class.

Im trying to set it up such that if T is a child of num it will process comparisons differently than if they were strings.

To me, this goes back to the polymorphism-inheritance design of *is-a* and *has-a* relationshis.

Comment: Do you actually want to check if a `Type` instance is a subtype of `num` of if the runtime type of a value is the subtype of `num`? Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682371 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## 1. The Answer

With `int is num` you test if an instance of `Type` is a subtype of `num` which is correctly reported as `false`.

What you want to test is rather like `5 is num`.

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/17736bb69be14f506a3b).

## 2. Additional, Useful Info

As noted in the comments, it's also useful to note that `is` tests for the runtime type. So, if you're working with a non-initialized variable — e.g., `int nonInitializedVar;` —, with runtime type of `Null`, Dart will return `false` to the `is` test, because `Null` is not a subclass of `num`.

Another important point is that if you want to use `is` on types (classes) at runtime you will need to use reflection, with packages such as `dart:mirrors` or `reflectable` or the dart-analyzer to do it at build time for code generation.

Comment: So in my cases of genericism, i would check if `_value is num` instead of `T is num` That sounds good.  I just wasnt sure if you could do it with classes as well, or if it was just the instantiated objects.  Thank you.

Comment: As a followon, if you did something like: `int test;`, you cant test `test` as a num, because while space is allocated, it is not set to anything, returning false;

Comment: With classes you need to use reflection ('dart:mirrors' or reflectable package).

Comment: `is` tests the runtime type. The runtime type of `int test;` is `Null`. `Null` is not a subclass of `num`.

Comment: Ok, I may have to use reflection if i cant use the runtime, thank you

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Thanks for the improvement. It's nor clear to me what you mean with "use is on classes" and "before runtime". `is` works with (custom) classes just fine and reflection is as well at runtime. Before runtime would be for example a code generation step where you use features from DartAnalyzer to get such information about existing source code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I think I misunderstood that. It would be better if you fixed it, as you seem more competent at it. What I had in mind was a statement like `CustomA is A`, which I thought should give me `true` if `CustomA` either implemented or inherited `A`. As you can see, I haven't yet mastered this part of Dart yet. Anyway, improve/correct my edit as you see fit.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro no worries. "should give me `true`" - does it not? It's still not clear what you mean with "before runtime".

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that whole paragraph is just probably completely mistaken. What I was thinking about was that checking something like `CustomA is A` would be done at compile time because `CustomA` and `A` are simply classes or types. But `is` is a runtime check, so that shouldn't make sense (checks like this are runtime only anyway...); that's what you get when you write stuff at midnight :). Anyway, take a look at [this Dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/aa6fffc4b467e08eb06746ccc0cf8850), does that make sense in Dart?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Sorry, it was my fault. I didn't properly read what the question is about.